# Scala, Akka, Child Actor Why "discarded non-Unit value"?

Tags: scala, akka

Hello currently I get the following error on Scala while using Akka and Child Actors:

```
[warn] /Users/schmitch/projects/envisia/envisia-erp-loki/app/worker/CalculationWorker.scala:43: discarded non-Unit value
[warn]       } yield cb1).map { data =>
[warn]                        ^
[warn] one warning found
```

Currently my Actors recieve:

```
 override def receive = {
    case cm: CalculationModal =>
      val upper = sender() // To get the real sender we need to first have a good reference to him
      log.debug(s"Got a new calculation")
      (for {
        cb1 <- (cn ? true).mapTo[Boolean]
      } yield cb1).map { data =>

        log.debug(s"Callback1: $data")
        upper ! data
      }
  }
```

And the recieve of the child actor:

```
  override def receive = {
    case _ =>
      println(s"WS: $ws")
      sender() ! true
  }
```

However i don't know why I get this warning, since line 43 is the yield line which should be boolean and won't be discarded... Currently later on I want to have 2 child actors which have 2 callbacks cb1 and cb2 which will be calculated independently so that i have a little bit better concurrency.

Currently for my test they both just return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `map` to a `foreach`.

`receive` is `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` and calling `.map` on a `Future` produces another `Future`, not `Unit`. Calling `.foreach` instead *does* produce `Unit`.

Comment: could I change it that easily to a foreach?

Comment: i clarified my answer a bit and dropped the poor suggestion of inserting a `()` line as all that would have done is to return a `Future[Unit]`, which is still not a `Unit`.

Comment: Thanks. What I didn't knew is the PartialFunction[Any, Unit]. I thought if I have a ask pattern that I need to have some kind of return at the end, but as I found out the ask pattern just sends a Message to the sender(). However I need to declare `val mySender = sender()` and user `mySender ! "msg"` inside the foreach sind that will have his own sender().